Why users get locking errors when connecting to MS Access using C# with shared connection string?
I have a WPF app using C# that connects to a MS Access file to read and write data input by the user, and there are around 20 users that use the application almost daily (at one time, there may be around 5 users simultaneously running it). For that, I use OleDbConnection class, but errors regarding file lock happened, like these:

System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80004005): User 'Admin' has put the database in a state that prevents it from being opened or blocked.


System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80004005): Could not lock file.


System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80004005): Could not use "db.accdb". File already in use.

These are always thrown when I try to open the connection with the database. After some research, I found numerous questions on SO (like this or this or even this) as well as other repositories, and they all tend to refer to the access mode when opening the Access file.
I have already tried setting my connection string to
$"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={ DBPath }; Mode = Share Deny None; Persist Security Info=False;"

specifying that nor read nor write access should be denied, according to this source, but users keep getting the errors.
How can I solve this issue?

Check that your application has been granted create and delete rights to the folder holding the database file, or it cannot create the .laccdb lock file.

@Gustav it has. This error doesn't happen every time, but rather every once in a while.

I have encountered this many times. 20 users and 5 concurrent, this is my upper limit. Here starts a process of either (1) chopping the backend-database into multiple pieces to go extremely on diminishing the number of concurrent users, or either (2) go for something like for instance "Sql Server Express"+"Sql Server Management Studio".

If the 5 concurrent users are 1 user that adds some order-lines and 4 users reading the order-data, you have a chance to find a solution inside Ms Access . . . I would say to buy you some time, before going over the a central database system for storing the data. If the 5 concurrent users are all at the same time entering order-data, you are at the limit of Ms Access as a viable database backend.

Are you sure the database is only being used through this application? If users (who must have access) choose to fiddle with the database directly these errors would be expected.

@JonRo SSMS is a DBA tool, not a database or database tool. MS Access can connect to SQL Server, using the same forms and reports. There's even an upsizing wizard for this

@ErikA while I can't guarantee no one else is using the file, I also highly doubt that, because it's on a file share that people have access to by default and don't really go on that folder, let alone its subfolders. People on the department aren't the most tech-savvy ones, and even handling files from one folder to another can be challenging from them - hence my desbelief.

What exactly is this application doing? If there are any design modifications or write operations on tables, the Mode in the string doesn't really matter. AFAIK Mode is more to set a lock to make sure your application can do certain operations, than to prevent the application from setting locks (e.g. if you deny others from writing, you can be sure you can write without encountering write conflicts). Also, if the compact on close setting is enabled for that database, there are sure to be locks regardless of what your application is doing.

@ErikA there are write operations, but no design changes. I have SELECT, WRITE, UPDATE and DELETE commands throughout the application, and users can trigger any combination of those simultaneously.

This may be an exhibit of the popularly named Monster Bug where Access' database engine (ACE) and Windows are in infight about caching network traffic.
It is mentioned here, and officially documented here:
Access reports that databases are in an 'inconsistent state'
This page also lists the only known workaround:
disable the leasing on the machine where the shared database is stored
including the changes in the Registry to achieve this.
Should you perform this change and should that lead to reliable results, please report back here and also use the feedback option at the bottom of the Microsoft page as that info will reach the Access engineering team.

The file is not stored on a machine, it's stored on a file share.

Yes, or the file could not be shared. But a file share is hosted on a machine; it is that machine the workaround relates to.

Ah right. In that case, I'm afraid I can't test the workaround - that machine is probably a computer in Europe (where my company's HQ is) and I don't have access to that.

That - a long distance connection with some latency - could also be the issue. Access is quite sensitive to that. It might be worth the trouble to move the backend to SQL Server (Express).

Yes, tired of running into that. Now looking for SQLite migration.

@krobelusmeetsyndra we are at 2024 and for finding perfect fiting solution to your problem must be done by you and this requires learn techs. that u will use.
SQLite also has some limitations on multipler users ! It uses lock mecanism, means while a database operation happening others waits for it to comlete! I hope you can understand what this means if you have clients more then 15 or complex operations !

@kanpinar is right. You will probably face similar issues with SQLite which also is a single file shared engine. Alternatives to SQL Server are rather PostgrSQL and MySQL but first check if your data will fit into the limitations of the SQL Server Express edition.

@krobelusmeetsyndra "tired of running into that". Do we have to interpret this as "Sql Server is not an option as a solution"?  I can imagine the IT department is opposed to this. Keep in mind, you can also rent a cloud Sql Server.

@JonRo you can interpret that as "tired of dealing with OleDB/Access".

For development purposes and POC I use mongodb also...

@krobelusmeetsyndra   So, we can rule “Microsoft Access” out as a part of the solution.  All the other file-based databases will also be out of the question given the number of users. And we end up with server-based databases. Giving “a WPF app using C#”, all Microsoft related, various Sql Server including the cloud one seem close relatives.

@krobelusmeetsyndra   Is it possible to save a copy of the database as an archive, and delete all information older than 6 months from the database you are using on the network?

@krobelusmeetsyndra  What do you expect from an answer in order to win the bounty? I can write about a bunch of trics to keep Ms Access afloat for some time, but this could be only a temporary fix as the use of your database keeps growing

@krobelusmeetsyndra  I do not think that “OleDB” is the culprit. Your application is using a city-car “Ms Access” as being it a limousine. In other words, too many (concurrent) users over a slughish network.

@JonRo I expected a solution for the issue, but workarounds aren't enough. Unfortunately, at my company and as far as I'm aware, we (common employees) are not allowed to use server-based databases, only official IT department. So I'm stuck with file-based ones...

If you need a multi-user database with write access for multiple users at a time, but can't run a server, nor can you access a file share with leasing disabled, you're pretty much out of luck. For SQLite, see when to use, you're failing the first item on their check list (and perhaps the second too).

are not allowed to use server-based databases -- I assume that means "cannot set up or host server DBs on our own". Then the solution seems obvious: talk to your manager, and get your IT to set up a SQL Server Express instance for you (or give access to an existing DB server).

First make sure that any other process didn't claimed that 'Access DB' by running it on it's own process especially when an other user opened that connection on separated process and no one else can use that connection unless it get closed and memory freed.
for example I have opened an office word document, at the same time I am trying to move it to an other directory. I'll have 'file in use' error or 'file is open in an other process' error & can't move it unless I close the document.
Second I don't know which design patter do you use. MVVM or … . But for sure when you have a DB with multiple simultaneous users accessing it, using singleton approach and let the .NET manage threads simultaneous would be best idea specially for something like Access Database that is not designed for such multithreading or multitasking scenarios as the way MSSQL or PostgreSQL or MySQL or … does.

Hello @krobelusmeetsyndra ,
there is a bounty, so I guess any solution/workaround could be interesting.

1. - Introduction.
1.1 - Motivation for this “Answer”.
The details “20 users” and “max 5 concurrent users” and a slughish network are a red flag. A red flag meaning that the application is reaching the workable limit of Ms Access.  I have seen a lot of databases reaching this limit, and generating all sorts of problems. I have seen my own databases reaching this limit, and had to take action.
IMHO, the fact that your application is using a file-based database is the main culprit. End of story. In short, I am gonna end up in advising to use a server-based database.
But . . . , awaiting such a conversion, what can be done to keep this application afloat.
Warning upfront: you are not gonna like what I will be suggesting, there are always drawbacks. But, I have tested and used these approaches myself. Main goal is to keep the stress on the MsAccess-file as low as possible.

1.2. - Assumptions.
I do not have enough information to linit my answer to your situation. So I am gonna make assumptions, and describe several approaches. I am gonna put each approach in a different “answer” in order to make it more efficient for writing comments.  (Unfortunately, I do not know how to get that done.)
As an example, I am gonna talk about a database with tables like “Products_T, ClientOrders_T, OrderLines_T, ClientInfo_T, Addresses_T, ZipCodes_T, AccountingCodes_T, DeliveryHeader_T, DeliveryLines_T”.

2. - Answers / solutions / workarounds / approaches / techniques.
2.1 - Year by year.
Let me assume, the application started on April 10th 2020. Take a copy of the huge-central-MsAccess-database, ald rename it to huge_database_yr2020. In this database you are gonna delete everything that is not created or edited in the year 2020, or has substantive relationships with year 2020 data e.g. the deliveries in 2021 from order issued in 2020.
Likewise, another copy renaming to “huge_database_yr2021”, and deleting everything not created or edited in 2021, or having relationships with year 2021 data. Same for the years 2022 and 2023.
For the huge_database_yr2024 I would make some changes to the above schema. For instance, keep client information for at least 2 years in the database.
Euh, do not forget to “Compact and Repair” ; - )  
Et voila, the database that the 5 concurrent users edit has become much smaller.
Now, your application must ask which year a user wants to open.  The year 2024 can be edited, the other years are read-only. Read-only can be programmed into your application, or you can bluntly set the database file properties to read-only using “Windows Explorer”.
Periodically you need all the information in one database for reporting?  Okay, copy the information in the seperate databases into a new “huge_database_allyears”. (You will get some errors about duplicates, but you are able to figure out a solution for this yourself.)

2.2.A - Chopping the database into pieces.
With my example described in paragraph 1.2, I am gonna split things up in 4 databases:

A =  Products_T, ZipCodes_T, AccountingCodes_T => I assume these do not change a lot, and can be seen as “read only”.
B =  ClientInfo_T, Addresses_T => depends on how many clients place multiple orders, or perhaps these data are maintained by a seperate specific group of users.
C =  ClientOrders_T, OrderLines_T
D =  DeliveryHeader_T, DeliveryLines_T

The database that the 5 concurrent users edit has gotten smaller, but not  as much as in 2.1. But the combined databases still contain all the data for all years.
Um . . . opening a clientorder with its lines (C), automatically means also opening the products (A) and the addresses (B) ?

2.2.B - Chopping the database into pieces.
Um . . . opening a client order with its lines (C), automatically means also opening the products (A) and the addresses (B) ?
Okay, we are gonna make it ugglier. Database C will get chopped down versions of the other tables, only the most necessary information, for the records effectively used in a relationship.

C =  ClientOrders_T, OrderLines_T, Products_someinfo_T, Client_someinfo_T

Frankly, I have used this in combination with 2.1, where the (A) was really huge. The combined solution made the backup procedures more tolerable.

2.3.A - Caching some data.
Since we have already divided the database into several files. Let us keep a “master” of database (A) en (B) on the server, and regularly copy these files to the local disk of the user.
You would think that the tables “Products_someinfo_T, Client_someinfo_T” can disappear, and the needed information could be retrieved from the local disk.
Um . . . my experience is that this does not help much.

2.3.B - Caching most of the data.
Taking it one step further, we also “cache” the database (C) and (D)! The word cache between brackets!
We can run the INSERT and UPDATE sql statements on the local cache file, and store a copy of the statements somewhere so that we can also run them on the central database, say once every 15 minutes.
The central database still stores all  informations for all years. But manipulation of this central database has been reduced to a bare minimum.
Hey, this is gonna create duplicate order numbers.  
** Bwah, you define a number range for each user.    
** After each insertion, they must “sync” with the central database
I have used this approach for many years! Okay, there are still some ifs and buts, but elaborating on this would take us too far today.
The huge advantage is that all information-only actions all happen on the local disk and do not affect the central database at all.
I warned upfront that there would be some ugly techniques that no one likes!

2.4 - Microsoft Access Replication.
I am sorry, I have no experience with this.

2.5 - Using a custom “MyOwnLockFile”.
I do not like this one at all, it is awfull, but I have used it. After all, desperate times call for desperate measures.
I am gonna customize the application so that only 2 or 3 users can access the database simultaneously. Therefore, wherever the application starts a connection, I am gonna perform the following procedure:
if fileexists(path/MyOwnLockFile_txt) then
  read file in memory, see an e.g. a bit downwards ;   close file-handle
else
  prepare the contents of a new file in memory
end if
if user1 = "" then user1 = ”1 / green / 20240926_131501”
elseif . . . 2 ; elseif . . . 3 ; else
  message “I am sorry, you have to wait for other users to quit the application”
  exit function
endif
write to “path/MyOwnLockFile_txt” the strings header, user1, user2, user3

e.g.
UserNbr / UserName / StartedConnectionAt
1 / brown / 20240926_131126
2 / 
3 / yellow / 20240926_131129

And off course, wherever the application terminates a connection, make sure your data is blank in this “path/MyOwnLockFile_txt” file.
This will generate a lot of other problems, for instance blocking the file “path/MyOwnLockFile_txt” . . .  But hey, the database is under less pressure.
It is probably not a long-term solution, but it buys some time.

3. - Conclusion?
This is a list of options, which have served a purpose, but are really not pleasant to handle. Some options have lasted more than 20 years (2.1). Other options usually end up in a server-based database system, often Ms Sql Server (Express), today a hosted version. 
For the future I foresee a move to Azure Sql Server (virtual machine in the cloud), and in the long run even to a (off premise) hosted MySql.

I suspect the DBPath? is shared location,
In that case maybe you can host the MS Access file in APP_Data folder in a ASP.NET project
and then expose some API so that your WPF app consumes the API.


mermaid.initialize({ startOnLoad: true });
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/font-awesome@4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mermaid/dist/mermaid.min.js"></script>

<pre class="mermaid">
  graph LR
  A[C# WPF APP]  --> B((Web API))
  B --> C((Kestrel/IIS))
  C --> D[MS Access file in APP_Data]
</pre>



If your WPF app is on client machine and MS access database is in different machine in a shared path then you are reinventing the wheel. MS already has encountered & resolved this using APP_DATA folder.
